# Got a parsing error while assign a value on my state

Tags: reactjs, class

## Hi friends,

I'm getting a little trouble putting that to work.
This method intend to put check if there's a product in the cart, if true, sum the same product.

```
    onAddProductToCart = (productId) => {
        const productInCart = this.state.productsInCart.find(
            (product) => productId === product.id
        );

        if (productInCart) {
            const newProductsInCart = this.state.productsInCart.map(product => {
                if(productId === product.id) {
                    return {
                        ...product,
                        quantity = product.quantity + 1
                    }
                }
                return product
            })
            
            this.setState({productsInCart: newProductsInCart})
        }
    };
```

I'm getting this error point to my assignment "=" bellow
Parsing error unexpected token:

```
quantity = product.quantity + 1
```

This method is inside the App class component , with has some mocked data.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        minFilter: "100",
        maxFilter: "2000",
        nameFilter: "Produto",
        productsInCart: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Produto 3",
                price: 300.77,
                photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/200?a=3",
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Produto 4",
                price: 400,
                photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/200?a=4",
                quantity: 2,
            },
        ],
    };
```

Comment: `quantity: product.quantity + 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use colon **: when set a object property**
return {
...product,
quantity:product.quantity + 1
}

Answer (score 0):

Using a colon would do the trick

```
quantity: product.quantity + 1
```